# import registry key as administrator

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

In my program I am trying to import a registry key upon an event however, I am receiving the error "Cannot import key: Error opening the file. There may be a disk or file system error.".

Looking at this I think it is due to me not running the process as an admin. My code is as follows:

```
   private void ImportRegKey_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >=6)
        {
             Process regeditProcess = Process.Start("regedit.exe", "Key.reg");
                 regeditProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        }
   }
```

Any advise would be appreciated, thanks.

**Edit**

The Key is part of the content of my project:
[image]

Comment: Where is the file `Key.reg` located?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I have added this as content in my project

Comment: So, can your program find the file when you don't run as administrator? What if you enter the full path of the file?

Comment: Yeah the program can find it. I also tired the below but same issue;

`var myDIR = new DirectoryInfo(string.Format(@"C:\TestKey\MyKeys\"));`
`string FileDirectory = myDIR.GetDirectories().OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).First().FullName;`

Comment: I know you can find it, but can the program find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have above should work:

```
 Process regeditProcess = Process.Start("regedit.exe", "Key.reg");
                 regeditProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
```

Remember though that spaces can cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging this turned out to be a space in the registry key name, removing this now works.